# Display a JavaScript array on a webpage

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items and need to display it on a page ,but instead im getting [object object] not the correct array.
My array is defined as var items.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I just need to find a way i can display the array on the webpage..

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array)`

Comment: i should explain little more and also post your code with question

Comment: @MdAman I am sorry but I am not allowed to share the code nor show the actual page ,all i can say is on the page i will open a modal that is supposed to show the array of items

Comment: @CoffeeOtaku i am not asking for whole code .. only the blog of code their you are getting error. this is for our better understanding.

Comment: @MdAman the problem is there is no error, it just doesnt want to display the info or array and instead drops me [object object].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is like this:

```
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
   document.writeln(items[i])
}
```

That will print each item in the array "items" on its own line.

If your array is actually nested, meaning arrays within the array, you need to loop through the loop.  Like this:

```
for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<items[i].length; j++) {
        document.writeln(items[i][j])
    }
}
```

What this will do is start counting at item[0].  It will print all the items inside as items[0][0], items[0][1], etc...
Then it will go to item[1] and start counting the items within that.

And so on...

Comment: It just gave me a full page of "object object" instead of the array data :L

Comment: If that's the case, then your array is not a single dimension array.  It sounds like it's an array of arrays.

Comment: apparently it is a "javascript print multidimensional associative array"

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.write(json_data);
```

Where `obj` is the object that currently writes [object object]

Comment: It does the right thing but it changes everything else on my webpage to the code.. is there some way i can have it inside a box or some items so my webpage wouldnt just be only an array?

Comment: Yes, use: document.writeln instead? Or, add the string to an existing object: document.getElementById('targetobject').innerHTML = json_data;